# Why is there no push force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram

I am having problems with this problem:

> A box is given a push so that it slides across the floor. How far will it go given that the coefficient of kinetic friction is 0.20 and the push imparts an initial speed of 4.0 m/s

So first I drew up my free body diagram:

[image]

I then ended up with this equation:

$$netforce = F_p - F_{fr}$$

So I assumed the net force acting on the object was friction due to the initial force applied to create a initial speed of 4m/s.

However, I was not able to reach any answers using this, so the explanation to this question is

$$netforce = F_{fr}$$

And then after that I can solve for acceleration and solve the problem. However, I do not understand, **how can net force only include friction when it was given an initial force to push it?**

Comment: After the box starts to move only the frictional force act on the box.

Comment: The force applied is what makes the box to move at an initial speed of 4 m/s. That force is not continuous. If it were applied continuously, it would accelerate the box in the said direction. Now that there is only frictional force left to act on the moving box (continuous), this decelerates the box until it stops moving.

Comment: I recommend that you simply replace the *"A box is given a push so that it slides across the floor"* with *"A box has an initial speed of $4.0 m/s$"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The push force given by the problem **is just to put it into motion.**

In a surface where the coefficient of friction is greater than zero, that is, where can exist a force of friction contrary to motion, the objects tend to get closer and closer to stopping, in relation to the ground, as time passes.

So you can consider that the object was there for a long time, with no motion related to the ground and some push force put it into motion and, when it got to *4 m/s* the force stopped to act. That's what the problem means by *"and the push imparts an **initial speed** of 4.0 m/s"*.

That is why you consider just the force due to friction on the body diagram. The moment where you start counting the time (or the distance it went) is when the push force lets go, so there is only the force due to friction.

And that's it, the rest is just make the calculations.